# Vivado Error : static elaboration of top level verilog design unit(s) in library work failed

Tags: verilog

I have written the following code in Verilog using gates:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module flip_flop (d,clk,q,q_bar);
input [36:0] d;
input clk;
output [36:0] q;
output [36:0] q_bar;
wire dbar,x,y;
not(dbar,d);
nand(x,clk,d);
nand(y,clk,dbar);  
nand(q,q_bar,y);
nand(q_bar,q,x);
endmodule

module adder(A,B,S);
input [36:0] A;
input [36:0] B;
output [36:0] S;
assign S = A + B;
endmodule

module subtractor(A,B,S);
input [36:0] A;
input [36:0] B;
output [36:0] S;
assign S = A - B;
endmodule

module dec256sinc24b
(input mclk1, /* used to clk filter */
input reset, /* used to reset filter */
input mdata1, /* input data to be filtered */

output reg [15:0] DATA, /* filtered output*/
output reg data_en,
input [15:0] dec_rate
);

reg [36:0] MOUT;
reg [36:0] delta1;
reg [36:0] CNN1;
reg [36:0] CN1;
reg [36:0] CNN2;
reg [36:0] CN2;
reg [36:0] DN0;
reg [36:0] DN1;
reg [36:0] CN3;
reg [36:0] DN3;
reg [36:0] CN4;
reg [36:0] DN5;
reg [36:0] CN5;

reg [15:0] word_count;

reg word_clk;
reg enable;

/*Perform the Sinc action*/
always @ (mdata1)
if(mdata1==0)
    MOUT <= 37'd0;
    /* change 0 to a -1 for twos complement */
else
    MOUT <= 37'd1;

/*decimation stage (MCLKOUT/WORD_CLK) */
always @ (negedge mclk1, posedge reset)
begin
    if (reset)
        word_count <= 16'd0;
    else
    begin
        if ( word_count == dec_rate - 1 )
            word_count <= 16'd0;
        else
            word_count <= word_count + 16'b1;
    end
end

always @ ( negedge mclk1, posedge reset )
begin
if ( reset )
    word_clk <= 1'b0;
else
begin
    if ( word_count == dec_rate/2 - 1 )
        word_clk <= 1'b1;
    else if ( word_count == dec_rate - 1 )
        word_clk <= 1'b0;
    end
end

flip_flop M1(.d(MOUT),.clk(mclk1),.q(delta1));
adder M2(.A(CN1),.B(delta1),.S(CNN1));
flip_flop M3(.d(CNN1),.clk(mclk1),.q(CN1));
adder M4(.A(CN2),.B(CN1),.S(CNN2));
flip_flop M5(.d(CNN2),.clk(mclk1),.q(CN2));
flip_flop M6(.d(CN2),.clk(word_clk),.q(DN0));
flip_flop M7(.d(DN0),.clk(word_clk),.q(DN1));
subtractor M8(.A(DN0),.B(DN1),.S(CN3));
flip_flop M9(.d(CN3),.clk(word_clk),.q(DN3));
subtractor M10(.A(CN3),.B(DN3),.S(CN4));
flip_flop M11(.d(CN4),.clk(word_clk),.q(DN5));
subtractor M12(.A(CN4),.B(DN5),.S(CN5));

/* Clock the Sinc output into an output register
WORD_CLK = output word rate */

always @ (negedge word_clk )
begin
    case ( dec_rate )
        16'd32:begin
            DATA <= (CN5[15:0] == 16'h8000) ? 16'hFFFF : {CN5[14:0], 1'b0};
        end
        16'd64:begin
            DATA <= (CN5[18:2] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : CN5[17:2];
        end
        16'd128:begin
            DATA <= (CN5[21:5] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : CN5[20:5];
        end
        16'd256:begin
            DATA <= (CN5[24:8] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : CN5[23:8];
        end
        16'd512:begin
            DATA <= (CN5[27:11] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : CN5[26:11];
        end
        16'd1024:begin
            DATA <= (CN5[30:14] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : CN5[29:14];
        end
        16'd2048:begin
            DATA <= (CN5[33:17] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : CN5[32:17];
        end
        16'd4096:begin
        DATA <= (CN5[36:20] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : CN5[35:20];
        end
        default:begin
            DATA <= (CN5[24:8] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : CN5[23:8];
        end
    endcase
end

/* Synchronize Data Output*/
always@ (negedge mclk1, posedge reset )
begin
    if ( reset )
    begin
        data_en <= 1'b0;
        enable <= 1'b1;
    end
    else
    begin
        if ( (word_count == dec_rate/2 - 1) && enable )
        begin
            data_en <= 1'b1;
            enable <= 1'b0;
        end
        else if ( (word_count == dec_rate - 1)  && ~enable )
        begin
            data_en <= 1'b0;
            enable <= 1'b1;
        end
        else
            data_en <= 1'b0;
    end
end

endmodule
```

But, I am getting the following errors while running the code:

```
primitive output connection must be a scalar net at line 12 (nand(q,q_bar,y);)

static elaboration of top level verilog design unit(s) in library work failed
```

I would appreciate if anyone could please let me know what are the issues in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

The error message means that you can not connect a 37-bit vector net (`q`) to the output port of the `nand` primitive gate instance.

The Verilog built-in gate primitives are different from modules in this respect.  Modules support multi-bit ports, but primitives only support single-bit ports when you instantiate a single gate.

However, primitives do support instance arrays where the primitive keyword is followed by an instance name and a range specifier.  You can fix the syntax error by changing:

```
nand(q,q_bar,y);
```

to:

```
nand n1 [36:0] (q,q_bar,y);
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 28.3.6 *Primitive instance connection list*.

---

Another likely problem is that the following line probably does not do what you want:

```
not(dbar,d);
```

`d` is 37 bits, whereas `dbar` is a single bit.

Also, `x` and `y` are single bit.  You should check all your connections.

---

Finally, it is notoriously difficult to model flip flops using primitives like this in Verilog because flip flops are feedback circuits.  Save yourself a lot of trouble and use the appropriate modeling style: behavioral using `@(posedge clk)` like you are doing elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a multi-bit operation on `primitives` here `nand(q,q_bar,y);` can be used for single bit. Try using a genvar.
Also the net `y` is single bit so check if that's correct because eventually `y`   will settle to `y = ~(q[36] & q[36]);`

```
genvar i;
 generate
  for(i=0i<37;i++)
   nand(q[i],q_bar[i],y);
 endgenerate
```